# Using manuel segues with Swift Spritekit

Tags: swift, segue, transition

(Swift) I have a problem with my app, I'm working on. It features a SpriteKit Scene and some transitions to different scenes. However, from the main menu of the app, I've created a segue to a new viewController via Story Board.

My problem is, when I - in my sprite kit scenes, browse back to the main menu to trigger the Story Board scene my app crashes.

I can only use the Story Board segue if restart my App and triggers it from the main menu as the first thing.

Also, when I get back to my Sprite Kit Scene from the new viewController, I cannot use any of the nodes (as buttons) to make transitions to other sprite kit scenes.

I've tried to illustrate it here: 
[image]

Code for calling the segue:

```
    func goto_achievements() {
    self.viewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("achievements", sender: self)
}
```

Any help appreciated!